# Plotting in a for loop: Why can't I subtract from the counter?

Tags: r, for-loop, plot, counter

Why does the following code plot points at `1:10` and not at `0:9` on the x axis?
(I know I can code it differently to solve the problem, nevertheless, I wish to know.)

```
y <- rep(1,10)

for (i in 1:10) {

          if (i == 1) {
                    plot(y[i]~(i-1),pch = 14,
                         ylim = c(0,2),
                         xlim=c(0,11))
          }
          else {points(y[i]~(i-1), pch = 14)
          }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to use the `I()` (as-is) formula construct:

```
y <- rep(1,10)
for (i in 1:10) {
          if (i == 1) {
                    plot(y[i]~I(i-1),pch = 14,
                         ylim = c(0,2),
                         xlim=c(0,11))
          }
          else {points(y[i]~I(i-1), pch = 14)
          }
}
```

This is (according to `?I`) because arithmetic operators ("+", "-", "*" and "^") inside formulae are interpreted as formula operators (for adding/dropping terms or creating interactions) rather than as arithmetic operators.

You could obtain the same by changing your `plot` calls to: `plot(i-1,y[i],...)` to get out of formula mode.

Answer (score 2):

In formulas, the term `-1` is interepreted as "without intercept". Of course, this has no direct effect on your plot and hence is ignored.

Note that the term `-1` is a special case. You will receive an error message if you use, for example, `-2` in your formula.